# RegEx to include a lot of different characters

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have some problems creating a regular expression to use in my jQuery Validating.
I have a field, that can include the following characters: Latin letters, danish locale symbols and diacritical signs, digits, dot, whitespace, apostrophe, underscore and hyphen.

So far I've got this regex:

```
/^[-\sa-åA-Å]+$/i.test(value)
```

This makes sure that the field can include danish letters, hyphen and whitespace.

Can anyone help me creating the correct regex for the above characters?

Comment: Isn't your regex working for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "different characters" ??

Comment: Yeah that one above is working, but i need it to include: apostrophe, underscore and hyphen, and characters like ü and so.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Danish symbols to your RegExp via their Unicode codepoint (i.e. `\u0020` for a space). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) should have a list of the Unicode characters.

Comment: Use Google Cache to view Wikipedia if you need it now.

Comment: Disable Javascript to see wikipedia today, or visit it on a mobile device. BTW literal characters in RegEx are preceded by a counter slash (\- \\ \s \å \Å) (\s is for space)

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode ranges and Unicode values in Reg Exp.

for some help:

1. http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block
2. http://unicodelookup.com/